# Trouble with two table join and Group By working together

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Using Oracle SQL developer and I'm currently trying to solve this problem:
*Provide an alphabetic list of students (student last name followed by first name) who have an overall grade average of 93 or higher. The name should be one column, last name first and sorted on last name then first name.*

This is my query, which is returning :"not a Group By expression"

```
SELECT Student.Last_Name || ', ' || Student.First_Name AS "Student Name"
FROM Student, Grade
WHERE Student.Student_Id = Grade.Student_Id
GROUP BY Grade.Student_Id
HAVING AVG(Grade.Numeric_Grade) > 92
ORDER BY Last_Name;
```

I'm a little confused using a group by and a two table join, and I'm hoping some more experienced eyes could take a look at it.  Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, learn to use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  Second, the unaggregated columns in the `SELECT` need to match the `GROUP BY` columns.  Third, use table aliases:

```
SELECT s.Last_Name || ', ' || s.First_Name AS "Student Name"
FROM Student s JOIN
     Grade g
     ON s.Student_Id = g.Student_Id
GROUP BY s.Last_Name || ', ' || s.First_Name
HAVING AVG(g.Numeric_Grade) > 92
ORDER BY s.Last_Name || ', ' || s.First_Name;
```

In the event that two students have the same name, you might want to include `s.Student_Id` in the `GROUP BY` as well.

Comment: My textbook had this (apparently) wrong syntax for joins, I'll read up on W3 about those and the table aliases to make sure I'm all clear moving forward. The change you made to the group by statement makes sense as well.  Thank you so much!

Comment: @cdaiga got it! sorry, first post here so i'm just figuring out how to work things.

Comment: Welcome to SO @stasis100t.

Comment: @cdaiga It is a very bad idea to urge the OP to upvote/accept an answer 7 minutes after it was posted. Especially if it is a wrong answer. "it works" is a statement that I don't like here because most of the time it means "for my test data set the solution returns the expected result". Better try to understand the solution. The OP wants to group by `StudentId`, the answer groups by `Last_Name || ', ' || First_Name`. Are these the same groups?

Comment: @stasis100t It is not a good idea to accept an answer immediately after it is posted. It is better to wait at least one day before accepting a post. Here you actually have accepted a wrong answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no need  to use the INNER JOIN syntax. I prefer the
   classical syntax which is related to the relational algebra notation
   and that looks more natural to me.
2. in the select-list and the having list there can only be expression from the group-by-list or aggregate functions of expressions.
3. you should carefully check if the groups you build are the groups you want.  If you group by `s.Last_Name || ', ' || s.First_Name` then
   you don't differ between two students with the same `First_Name` and
   `Last_Name`. That makes no sense. Use the primary keys of the table
   to group.
4. if you want you can simplify the order by clause by using the the order number of the expression in the select list
5. Always double check if the inner join is appropriate or an outer join is needed.

so use the `StudentId` in your group by list.

For technical reasons add the `FirstName` and the `LastName` to the group-by, too:

```
SELECT 
    Student.Last_Name || ', ' || Student.First_Name AS "Student Name"
FROM 
    Student, 
    Grade
WHERE 
    Student.Student_Id = Grade.Student_Id
GROUP BY 
    Student.Student_Id, 
    Student.Last_Name,
    Student.First_Name
HAVING 
    AVG(Grade.Numeric_Grade) > 92
ORDER BY 
    1, 
    Student.Student_Id
```

Alternatively can also use the expression of the select-list in the group-by clause

```
SELECT 
    Student.Last_Name || ', ' || Student.First_Name AS "Student Name"
FROM 
    Student, 
    Grade
WHERE 
    Student.Student_Id = Grade.Student_Id
GROUP BY 
    Student.Student_Id, 
    Student.Last_Name || ', ' || Student.First_Name
HAVING 
    AVG(Grade.Numeric_Grade) > 92
ORDER BY 
    1, 
    Student.Student_Id
```

Note that wee need the StudentId in the group-by clause The expression `Student.Last_Name || ', ' || Student.First_Name` we have only for technical reasons in the group by clause. If we dont we will get an error. We can avoid this expression in the group by clause. `Student.Last_Name || ', ' || Student.First_Name` is the same for all elements in a group, the MAX (or MIN) function chooses one of these identical values.

```
SELECT 
    MAX(Student.Last_Name || ', ' || Student.First_Name) AS "Student Name"
FROM 
    Student, 
    Grade
WHERE 
    Student.Student_Id = Grade.Student_Id
GROUP BY 
    Student.Student_Id, 
HAVING 
    AVG(Grade.Numeric_Grade) > 92
ORDER BY 
    1, 
    Student.Student_Id
```

If you want to select all students that haven't more then 3 grades an inner join is wrong:

```
-- incorrect statement
SELECT 
    Student.Last_Name || ', ' || Student.First_Name AS "Student Name"
FROM 
    Student, 
    Grade
WHERE 
    Student.Student_Id = Grade.Student_Id
GROUP BY 
    Student.Student_Id, 
    Student.Last_Name || ', ' || Student.First_Name
HAVING 
    count(*) <=3
ORDER BY 
    1, 
    Student.Student_Id
```

Here you have to use an outer join. Otherwise the students with 0 grades will not be displayed

```
SELECT 
    Student.Last_Name || ', ' || Student.First_Name AS "Student Name"
FROM 
    Student 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Grade
        ON Student.Student_Id = Grade.Student_Id
GROUP BY 
    Student.Student_Id, 
    Student.Last_Name || ', ' || Student.First_Name
HAVING 
    count(*) <=3
ORDER BY 
    1, 
    Student.Student_Id
```

Again it is important to use the primary key in the group-by-clause.